# Pandas DataFrame - Selecting and Indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this dataframe pandas object

```
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),['A','B','C','D','E'],['W','X','Y','Z'])
```

I execute and this is the table of rows `A, B, C, D, E` and `W, X, Y, Z` columns

[image]

Each one of these `W, X, Y, Z` columns are really a Pandas Series, `W` is a Pandas series and `X` and `Y` and `Z`, and all them share a common index.

This is basically that's a data frame, a series set which shares an index.

Until here that's OK. :)

I can grab all data values of W column greater than 0 of this way:

Note that C rows are disappear

[image]

But I don't understand the following:

What is the mean of this sentence?

```
df[df['W']>0][['Y','X']]
```

The result is this:

[image]

In theory, I am grabbing all data frame `W` column values which be greater than 0 and I ahead that just return the `Y` and `X` columns based on what criteria or condition?

Why is the reason by which I grab these values on `Y` and `X` columns?

Currently, I am studying Pandas and I would like to know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: df[df['W']>0][['Y','X']] when W is more than 0 , getting the column of Y and  X

Comment: `df[df['W']>0]` returns a dataframe after applying  your filter condition. Then `["Y", "X"]` accesses the columns `Y` and `X` of that DataFrame.

Comment: The "proper" or idiomatic way to do this selection is to use .loc, `df.loc[df['W']>0,['Y','X']]`

Comment: @ScottBoston using .loc have some related with performance or memory when the selection operation is performed?

Comment: @bgarcial You should reframe from chaining selections, in general. To spot chaining look for ']['.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=chain%20indexing#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `df['W']>0` returns a boolean series where the column is greater than zero (`true`) else false
2. `df[df['W']>0]` returns all rows from the `df` where the `df['W']>0` is `true`
3. `df['X']` returns the column 'X' of the dataframe
4. Similarly, `df[['X', 'Y']]` returns the columns `X` & `Y` from the dataframe

as you can see, the syntax `df[...]` can take on different meanings:

1. it can be used to mask the dataframe by rows by passing a boolean series the same length as the data frame
2. it can be used to select a single column (pass in a string) or a group of column (pass in a list of strings)

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
df[df['W']>0]
```

a new `data frame` is returned. Thus, when you put `[['Y', 'X']]` in the end of this data frame, you're basically doing a simple selection in this new data frame. The values that will appear in column `X` and `Y` are just the values for `X` and `Y` of this df.

In more detail, `df['W']>0` will return a `Boolean` series, i.e. a series with values `True` or `False`. When you do `df[df['W']>0]` you are filtering your `df` using this series. The output will be rows of your `df` where `df['W']>0` returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

As you explained in the 1st 2 steps:

1. Returns Y, X columns

```
df[['Y','X']]
```

2. Returns rows where W > 0

```
df[df['W']>0]
```

3. Third step: Returns rows where W > 0 and then we select Y, X columns

```
df[df['W']>0][['Y','X']]
```

Basically first we apply function 1 to data frame, then on the output function 2 is applied. Hence the final output.

It's sequential execution of functions.

Answer (score 1):

It performs two independent operations in a oneliner.

1. (Filtering rows) `df[df['W'] > 0]` selects only rows where the W column is positive
2. (Filtering columns) `df[['X', 'Y']]` selects only 2 columns of interest

Answer (score 1):

If you compare this Python code to for example excel you could state:

```
IF(W>0,"Value if True(return Y and X)", "Value if False ("")")
```